# Could not load javascript file because of wrong MIME-Type (Spring Boot 2, Thymeleaf, Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing a small spring boot application for educational purposes and learning how to work with thymeleaf and bootstrap.

I've used thymeleaf layout decorating to create a good layout template and so far it works fine. On one page I want to open a pop-up window for user inputs and so I used jquery. Besides the integration of bootstrap/webjars I had to write an extra javascript file and put it into resources folder (resources/static/js/main.js). When I test the application (as local jar with embedded tomcat) I can see the page but I get an error, so the main.js is not loaded.

The error looks like:

> Das Skript von "http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.js" wurde
>   geladen, obwohl sein MIME-Typ ("application/json") kein für JavaScript
>   gültiger MIME-Typ ist.
>
> Engl.: The script of "http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.js" was
>   loaded, even though its mime type (“application/json”) is not a valid
>   javascript mime type.

The pop up window is not opening so I guess the javascript-file is not working.
The integration looks like

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../static/js/main.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

I've also tried

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Neither worked.
Does anybody know what is wrong or where to look for more details?

Here is the javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.table .btn_edit').on('click', function (event) {

    $('.staff_form #popup').modal();
});
});

Used versions:
Spring boot 2.1.7;
Thymleaf layout dialect 2.4.1;
Bootstrap 4.3.1  --> webjars;
JQuery 3.4.1     --> webjars
```

A screenshot of the folder structure of the resources folder.
The resources/templates/user/index.html should open the javascript file.

[image: folder structure of resources folder]

Comment: That error is so common and it's description is terrible. It comes up when the server can't find the resource to serve to the client, so it's a route problem. Can you post a picture of your folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your main.js file, so that thymeleaf resolves the context:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
```

And if it doesn't work out of the box, add this to whatever class you use to extend your webconfig, or add the class itself if you don't have one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer    {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. May I ask further, what is the difference between th:src and src?

Comment: @AndréSchmidt without consulting the documentation (I know this out of using th:src and the @{..} syntax) thymeleaf is capable of pre-appending your application context to an url specified with th and @{..}, so that if the application context changes depending on stuff like the server you are deploying in, it will still work.