# Thymeleaf can not read files in static folder

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am making a blog app using spring boot and as a template engine I got Thymeleaf. Problem is, that suddenly I am not able to load any files under static folder. In order to use css styles I just put  tag in html but images are also a problem. First of all, when css files are loaded my browser block this files due to MIME exception. What is funny, that in empty project made in springboot initializer it is working fine, also I added the same project dependencies like spring boot security etc. Whats more, I am able to load google fonts as type="text/css". When I switch to visual studio code, my css and js code are working just fine. My folder structure is normal for spring boot project, made in spring boot initializer. My path must be ok, because in new project with the same html css files, I can load this files but when I added my whole project it is broken again and http 405 error in google devtools. It is normal project using h2 database with commandLineRunner and some security.
Project https://github.com/orestwojtowicz/blog-spring/tree/backend

````
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/main.css}
<link type="text"css" src="../static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}
```[project structure][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0uhs.png


UPDATE: I was able to get rid off MIME error by adding additional springBoot security configuration but all static files are still blocked HTTP 405 error.
````

@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
    }

```
OK UPDATE v2.0, Now I know what is causing this issue. It is Controller....
```

```
@PostMapping
public String registerNewUser(@Valid User user, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult,
                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        // prevent from adding not complete user object
        model.addAttribute("validationErrors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());

        return "auth/register";
    } else {

    }
    User newUser = userEntityService.registerNewUser(user);
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", newUser.getId())
            .addFlashAttribute("success", true);



    return "redirect:/register";
}
```

I do now know why this method cause this issue, but will solve this problem soon.

```
PROBLEM SOLVED
I should use     @PostMapping("/register") instead of @PostMapping....
```

Comment: do You have any stack trace that You could add to Your question?

Comment: my application just start fine, without any errors

Comment: in Your security configuration try to change .antMatchers("/").permitAll() to .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() and You have doubled http.csrf().disable();.

Comment: Instead of src try href. You should put it like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}">    .. Moreover, co-incidentally I have a project in github which has the same structure as yours - take a look at here - https://github.com/ajkr195/Code-Incubator/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/fragments/header.html

Comment: I still got 405 error on all files in static. It is still MIME error The resource from “http://localhost:8080/css/login.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: Thanks Ajay, but I tried also this way yesterday :P and still the same problem.

Comment: Ball park: Have you copied and pasted the code from somewhere? or you personally typed in your IDE? Sometimes char coding might also issue such messages. It may not help but its worth a shot.

Comment: I wrote everything by myself. It is really strange, because in empty project my view layer is working just fine. Maybe I just need to copy and paste to new project class, by class and see what is going on in google devtools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load javascript file because of wrong MIME-Type (Spring Boot 2, Thymeleaf, Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079331/could-not-load-javascript-file-because-of-wrong-mime-type-spring-boot-2-thymel)

Comment: Thanks Jorge, but I was trying to load files in different way, with th:href and without it. The result is always the same. I added additional configuration for WebConfig but still the same problem ;/